# Spring and IoC for my Singleton class (web-app, Tomcat)

Tags: java, spring

I have such singleton class:

```
package ua.org.bytes.ewt;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;
import ua.org.bytes.ewt.dao.CategoriesManager;
import ua.org.bytes.ewt.dao.ShortcutsManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Vitaliy Ganzha
 */
public class ApplicationSupervisor {
    private static final ApplicationSupervisor INSTANCE = new ApplicationSupervisor();
    private CategoriesManager categoriesManager;

    public void setCategoriesManager(CategoriesManager categoriesManager) {
        this.categoriesManager = categoriesManager;
    }

    public void setShortcutsManager(ShortcutsManager shortcutsManager) {
        this.shortcutsManager = shortcutsManager;
    }
    private ShortcutsManager shortcutsManager;

    public ShortcutsManager getShortcutsManager() {
        return shortcutsManager;
    }

    private ApplicationSupervisor(){
        /*WebApplicationContext context =
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(
                    ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
        );

        categoriesManager = (CategoriesManager)context.getBean("categoriesManager");
        shortcutsManager = (ShortcutsManager)context.getBean("categoriesManager");*/
    }

    public static ApplicationSupervisor getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * @return the categoriesManager
     */
    public CategoriesManager getCategoriesManager() {
        return categoriesManager;
    }

}
```

And applicationContext.xml:

```
    <beans default-autowire="autodetect">
    <bean id="categoriesManager" class="ua.org.bytes.ewt.dao.CategoriesManagerImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="shortcutsManager" class="ua.org.bytes.ewt.dao.ShortcutsManagerImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="applicationSupervisor" class="ua.org.bytes.ewt.ApplicationSupervisor" singleton="true">
        <property name="categoriesManager">
            <ref local="categoriesManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="shortcutsManager">
            <ref local="shortcutsManager"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

So, I had one class with all entity managers. All implementations on interfases CategoriesManager and ShortcutsManager I want to set with Spring IoC.
I've added listener into web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

But when I try to work with them, I get NullPointerException: 
ApplicationSupervisor.getInstance().getShortcutsManager(); = will return null.

Please, help me, I'm new in Spring IoC.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working because you have two singletons, not one. The first singleton is managed by `ApplicationSupervisor.getInstance()`, the second is managed by Spring. You haven't told Spring about the `getInstance()` factory method.

You need to declare your Spring bean to use `getInstance()`:

```
<bean id="applicationSupervisor" class="ua.org.bytes.ewt.ApplicationSupervisor" 
         factory-method="getInstance">
    <property name="categoriesManager">
        <ref local="categoriesManager"/>
    </property>
    <property name="shortcutsManager">
        <ref local="shortcutsManager"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that `singleton="true"` is redundant here - all Spring beans are singletons by default.

With this configuration, you can access the singleton either through Spring's `BeanFactory`, bean injection, or programmatically via `ApplicationSupervisor.getInstance()`.

However, this is not really a nice way to go about managing your singetons. Rather than having a static `getInstance()`, you should be injecting the `ApplicationSupervisor` into the beans that use it. This is the whole point of IoC.

Comment: I think about injecting ApplicationSupervisor into beans, but I refused this idea, because I have a lot of beans, and maybe, i'll have a plugins system, that will use those object.

Comment: *Not that singleton="true" is redundant here* I guess you mean *Note that ...*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this to load your Application supervisor?

Spring doesn't hook into the java 'new' keyword

```
static {
    INSTANCE = (ApplicationSupervisor) 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/ApplicationContext.xml").getBean("applicationSupervisor");
}
```